# Knockout mapping plugging does not work properly

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

Hi I have been getting investing alot of time in learning Knockout and have come to a point where I have to many properties in my application and I am in need to use the mapping pluggin.

It seems easy enought how it should be used but I mussed be missing something because it does not work.I have created a test example.This is my code:

```
 function vm() {
            var self = this;
            this.viewModel = {};
            this.getData = function() {
                $.getJSON('/api/Values/Get').then(data)
                    .fail(error);

                function data(ajaxData) {
                    console.log(ajaxData);
                    self.viewModel = ko.mapping.fromJS(ajaxData);
                    console.log(self.viewModel);
                }

                function error(jError) {
                    console.log(jError);
                }
            };
        };

        ko.applyBindings(new vm());
```

This is my html:

```
        <ul data-bind="foreach: viewModel">
        <li data-bind="text:FirstName"></li>
        <input type="text" data-bind="value: FirstName"/>
    </ul>
    <button data-bind="click : getData">Press me!</button>
```

My ajax call succesfully retrieves this data from the server:

```
[
   {
     FirstName: "Madalina",
     LastName: "Ciobotaru",
     hobies: [
          "games",
          "programming",
          "hoby"
           ]
   },
   {
     FirstName: "Alexandru",
     LastName: "Nistor",
     hobies: [
        "games",
        "programming",
        "movies"
        ]
   }
]
```

It seems that after data function is called viewModel get's converted into an array but with no items in it.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have taken your expected server data and created a [jsfiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/B8mav/2/). You needed to change the viewModel property to be an observable array, and change the way the mapping is performed.

Here is a version of your script that will work:

```
function vm() {
    var self = this;
    this.viewModel = ko.observableArray([]);
    this.getData = function() {
        $.getJSON('/api/Values/Get').then(data)
            .fail(error);

        function data(ajaxData) {
            console.log(ajaxData);
            ko.mapping.fromJS(ajaxData, {}, self.viewModel);
            console.log(self.viewModel);
        }

        function error(jError) {
            console.log(jError);
        }
    };
};

ko.applyBindings(new vm());
```